# Outward front door security

Tags: security, front-door

I live in a condo with 8 units in the building. Half of the residents are gone in April-October and that increases the unit security concerns.

The houses in the condo association are spaced apart with no building directly in front or behind my building. In fact, the back side of my unit is facing a golf course.

We are experiencing some night time activities this year which we never had before. The entries to every unit are sort of isolated from each other, even the second floor units have their own separated stairways. The stairway (breezeway) is open, but has blind spots where an intruder can hide.

I have an **outward** front door and just one lock that could be easily opened. What are the solutions to prevent intruders from entering when I am sleeping at night, by simply picking the lock.

Update: It appears that I need a Nightlock Door security device. I found one, but it "Works ONLY on Outward swinging wood doors with commercial metal frames. NO METAL DOORS!"

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you rent or own the condo? Can you post a pic. of the outside?

Comment: I own the condo

Comment: There are different qualities of locks.  Some easy to pick and some a PITA to pick.  A locksmith will be the best person to answer your questions.

Comment: But I want some sort of security I can control from the inside.

Comment: I’m assuming the answer is yes, but do you have hinges with security pins? (You’ll see a small hex grub screw in the middle of the hinge when the door is open.)

Comment: Yeah, I'd be worried about someone just tapping out the hinge pins and opening the door from the hinge side, pulling the bolts out of the jam as they do so. They might make enough noise to wake you up if you're home, but they could easily do this while you're not home. Adding a security camera might deter some people. Even a _fake_ security camera might make them pass to a door that looks "safer"...

Comment: the hinges on the door are standard exterior hinges

Comment: I'd _strongly_ recommend asking the condo association about the security of those hinges. It's _so_ easy to tap hinge pins out, then just pry the door open from that side. I can't fathom that they'd do that. Maybe they're security hinges (something preventing the pin from being removed unless the door is already open) and you just don't see the security measure because you don't know what to look for (I wouldn't either).

Answer (score 4):

A couple things you can do:

**Replace your lock(s)**

Replace the upper deadbolt with a more secure one and/or replace the bottom doorknob with a lock version.

You can make them a matched set so you only need one key or leave them differently keyed.

[image]

**Add Security devices to inside of door.**

These can be simple latch types to actual bars:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it for an outward door? Doesn't look so.

Comment: Don't understand the photo with the red thing.

Comment: The "red thing" is a brace that prevent the door from being pulled open. Exactly what you may be needing.  Will it fit your particular door?  We don't know enough about your door and framing, that is the reason to consult a security professional.

Comment: @SantaMaria Yes all these are for outward or outswing doors. Just google "outward / outswing door security"

Comment: It's appears that I need a Nightlock Door security device. I found one, but  it "Works ONLY on Outward swinging wood doors with commercial metal frames.  NO METAL DOORS!"

Comment: @SantaMaria It's not obvious from your pics that this is a steel door. Please edit your original question to include that info. Also, that black bar in the 3rd photo looks like it's attached to a metal door frame. Not sure about your specific choice of "Nightlock Door" products, but maybe other brands are approved for metal door installation. You may also ask the mfgr _why_ they forbid metal doors and if they have any options that are approved for metal doors.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are in a condo, you need to bring your concerns to the condo management company and the Board of Directors.

Any modification outside your unit must have prior approval. However it is the responsibility of the Board to be sure the community is safe. That would mean proper lighting and mitigating any hiding places.

What can you do to the inside?  Consult a security expert.  Forward any suggestions for the exterior to the Management and Board. Subscribe to any suggestions for the interior of your unit.

Answer (score 2):

If your foremost concern is hearing your front door open, a simple door alarm will do that.  Battery powered door alarms have two parts, a magnet and a sensor.  One part mounts on the door and the other next to it on the wall.  When the door opens, the two are separated, causing the alarm to sound.  (You switch it off when you go out, and if you want, you can switch it back on with the pocket remote after you're out.). They are inexpensive ($10-50) and easy to install with double-back tape, no tools or wiring required.  For example (not an endorsement):[this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NYBF8LN) uses two common AA batteries and comes with a wireless remote that doubles as a panic button.
(I have designed security systems for homes and schools, and believe this is all you need to meet your objective of waking you up if someone opens your door.  Perhaps more importantly, it should scare the intruder into fleeing and so avoid a confrontation.)

Answer (score 2):

If your concern is protecting the latch/bolt from attack (which is a legitimate concern for out-swinging doors), there are a number of products made which are basically a plate to cover that area of the door opening. I don't have any current recommendations for which might be best, but a currently practicing locksmith will be able to advise you and a "home center" may have them but not be able to give advice.

As others have said, this being a condo, make sure you have approval to make this change.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...

IMO, best bang for the buck (starting with the simplest):

- mandatory habit of closed and locked windows and doors
- light timers that are programmed with some regular and some random patterns when home is not occupied
- security and no trespassing signs
- eliminate outdoor hiding spots (e.g., overgrown bushes)
- motion sensing security lighting
- camera system; the sky is limit on what you want the system to be and do
- reinforced doors and increased window security (aftermarket security locks)
- guard service

It's worth mentioning that many police agencies provide a free onsite evaluation to residents. It's worth doing because they may have a perspective particular to your area/circumstance. Plus it never hurts to establish a friendly relationship to those who you might call in times of trouble...

Comment: Well, I am on the second floor. I am ONLY concerned with night time security when I am sleeping. Not when I am out.  Breaking the large window, which I have next to the front entry would wake me and others up. Picking the lock probably won't.

Comment: Thank you, but your advice doesn't apply to my situation. I just need to secure the door from inside. There are no daytime security concerns. I'm always home due to disability. Association takes good care of lights and bushes etc.

Comment: @Jimmy Fix-it,   most of what you listed cannot be done to the exterior of a condo without Board Approval.

Comment: @SantaMaria Getting a decent multipoint high-security lock and a similarly secure door does absolutely apply to your situation. A good lock requires serious effort (long drilling or an explosive charge) to defeat, and that should be more than enough to alleviate your concerns (because a burglar will then just pick your neighbour's door instead).

Answer (score 1):

A brief discussion on hinges, so that you can either recognize that you have them, or get them installed.

Links are not endorsements, they’re just for illustration.

For outswing doors, it’s possible that ordinary hinges can have their pins removed and the door easily opened without touching the lockset.

One strategy is non-removable pins.

[non removable pin example](https://www.stoneharborhardware.com/products/standard-hinge-non-removable-pin-4-inches-5-8-radius-corner-2-pack-satin-stainless-steel-by-stone-harbor-hardware?variant=4458638508094&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAz8GuBhCxARIsAOpzk8yPVoofe2g_Yo6hfmtcWNye_0iEiP2pQMywDZ3u2fBAKobw_HqLdoYaArJ-EALw_wcB)

The hinge pin has a groove cut in it with a grub screw set into that groove, so you can’t pop the hinge pin out without having the door open.

The other option is a tab that hooks into the adjacent hinge leaf.

[interlocking hinge leaves](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EVJHJRM)

This wouldn’t be my first choice, as it’s usually possibly to pry a door quite a distance away from the jamb, and this might be enough to open the door.

Third option is aftermarket studs that aim for the same effect as #2. I haven’t used them, largely because they require you to leave a screw out of the leaf and they might fail in a prying attack.

Changing hinges is well within the range of a typical handyman. To make the job easier, they should match the size (naturally!), corner radius, finish, and try to get as close as possible to thickness (though there are ways around a mismatch).